# How to get different context menu from qgraphicsitem inside a qgraphicsview?

Tags: qt, contextmenu, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem

I have a qgraphicsview it contains a scene and inside it there are some graphicsitem.
I have enabled the context menu in qgraphicsview by setcontextmenupolicy(qt::actionscontextmenu), but now my qgraphicsitem cannot receive any qgraphicsscenecontextmenuevent event. Thus only the context menu of qgraphicsview appear.

How could I solve this?

Comment: Please provide a code example; there appears not to be a function "setContextMenu" in the QGraphicsView: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qgraphicsview-members.html Did you mean setContextMenuPolicy?

Comment: Sorry it is setcontextmenupolicy. I will change it.

Comment: Just check if an item has been clicked and then call the context menu exec function directly for that item?

Comment: Sorry. But how to do this can you give more hint?

Answer (score 2):

in the code below I've created my own scene class, in inheriting from QGraphicsScene

Then re-implementing the `contextMenuEvent` I first check if there is an item at the event position, i.e. if I'm right clicking on an item in the scene.

If so, ill instead try to run any `contextMenuEvent` on that item.

If there is no item, or if it doesn't have its own `contextMenuEvent` ill just run the scene's version of the context event.

import PySide.QtGui as QtGui
import PySide.QtCore as QtCore

```
import PySide.QtGui as QtGui
import PySide.QtCore as QtCore

class MyScene(QtGui.QGraphicsScene):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
        # Check it item exists on event position
        item = self.itemAt(event.scenePos().toPoint())
        if item:
            # Try run items context if it has one
            try:
                item.contextMenuEvent(event)
                return
            except:
                pass

        menu = QtGui.QMenu()
        action = menu.addAction('ACTION')
```